# journals that publish urgent topics

Tags: publications, paper-submission

Is there any journal that publish on urgent matters? For instance, papers on epidemiological issues on animals.
I am aware of the existence of journals on the topic, however, the normal course of publishing can take minimum 6 months, the disease that I am working on, can take less than 6 months to be introduced in the area of interest.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered preprint servers?

Comment: Good recommendation! I did not know about their existence, is a great idea! Thank you!

Comment: Many fields have communications journals or sections devoted to work that deserve a somewhat faster publication. But although publication is relatively fast, they rather focus on papers which are self contained but not thoroughly done. For emergency consider other channels, like authorities, if that is the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some journals are known for rapid publications, e.g. [*PeerJ* (30 days to first decision)](https://peerj.com/benefits/#speed). Some publishers offer various venues for "accelerated publications", e.g. [this list at *Taylor & Francis*](https://taylorandfrancis.com/partnership/commercial/accelerated-publication/#journals_list). There is another list [here](https://www.editage.com/insights/a-list-of-journals-and-publishers-that-offer-rapid-publication?refer-type=article).

In general, you could simply ask the editor of any journal from your domain beforehand whether they would grant you an exceptionally speedy submission process for reasons pertaining to an emergency issue. It is possible that they will consider such a request.